# Getting difficulties which hyperparameters I have to select (5-Fold CV with optuna to find optimal GB regression model's hyperparameters)

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, hyperparameter, tuning

I'm currently searching best hyperparameters for a regression model of Gradient Boost, using 5-Fold Cross-Validation and OPTUNA.

However, I'm uncertain about which model's hyperparameters to choose, between **cases A and B** described below.

My code is like below:

---

```
    def params_model_gb(trial):
        params = {
          'n_estimators': trial.suggest_int('n_estimators', 10, 300),
          'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 2, 35),
          'learning_rate': trial.suggest_loguniform('learning_rate', 0.001, 0.1),
          'random_state': random_state
        }
       return params

    rmses_valids, r2_valids, distances_rmse, distances_r2, = [], [], [], []
    def objective(trial):
        params = params_model_gb(trial)
        kf = kFold(5)

        # cv start
        for train_index, valid_index in kf.split(train_val_data):
            train_data, valid_data = train_val_data.iloc[train_index], train_val_data.iloc[valid_index]
            X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = ~~
    
            # model load
            model = GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)
            model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
            # scores
            y_pred = model.predict(X_valid)
            rmse_train, rmse_valid, r2_train, r2_valid = ~~

            # append scores
            rmse_valids.append(rmse_valid)
            r2_valids.append(r2_valid)

            # append distances between train and valid scores
            distances_rmse.append(np.abs(rmse_train - rmse_valid))
            distances_r2.append(np.abs(r2_train - r2_valid))

        return np.mean(rmse_valids), np.mean(distances_rmse), np.mean(r2_valids), np.mean(distances_r2)

    # run objective
    study = optuna.create_study(directions=['minimize', 'minimize', 'maximize', 'minimize'], 
    sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(), pruner=optuna.pruners.HyperbandPruner())
            study.optimize(lambda trial: objective(trial), n_trials=50)
```

---

I obtained 50 sets of hyperparameter combinations and their results.

I've noticed that [1]mean_RMSE, [2]R-squared (r2), and [3]distances between train_valid sets exhibit variations. For example:

**Case A**: mean_**r2_valid: 0.5**, and mean_**r2_train: 0.9** : **r2 and RMSE values for the validation set are satisfactory**, but there is a notable difference when compared to the training set (**large distance**).

**Case B**: mean_**r2_valid: 0.46**, and mean_**r2_train: 0.52** : "**r2 and RMSE values for the validation set is normal**, and the **distance** between training and validation sets is **small**."

After training, I re-trained the model using both the hyperparameters from Case A and Case B with the combined train and validation data (train_val), and then made predictions on the test dataset. However, I obtained similar results.

---

My question is

1. **What should I select between Case A or B's hyperparameters** for research analysis when applying them to the real test set? Case A seems to be overfitting on training set, but has relatively high r2 on both cv-validation and real test set. Case B has relatively low r2 on test dataset, but seems to be not overfitted.
2. Is my code and approach acceptable? **Is it acceptable to choose hyperparameters by taking into account both the RMSE distance** (between the training and validation sets) and the **mean RMSE on the validation set?** Is it a valid approach to assign weights to the distance and RMSE on the validation set **(e.g., 0.3 x distance + 0.7 x RMSE on the validation set)** for the selection of the final hyperparameters that will be applied to the test set?

I have concerns because many people tune their models based on the mean RMSE scores from cross-validation on the validation set.